# PHPDocx Insert Data into an Existing .docx file

Tags: php, phpdocx

So far, this code works for me:

```
$docx = new CreateDocx();

$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, ' .
'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut ' .
'enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut' .
'aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit ' .
'in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. ' .
'Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui ' .
'officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';

$paragraphOptions = array(
   'b' => 'on',
   'font' => 'Arial'
);

$docx->addText($text, $paragraphOptions);

$docx->createDocx('template');
```

I can successfully create a word file...but how can I insert this paragraph from an existing Word Document? Im using PHPDocx Community edition

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge with PHPDocx community edition you can not work with existing templates.

The PRO edition let you insert content in an existing Word file but it is not free.